# Q question about proving isomorphism of abelian groups

Tags: finite-groups

Suppose that $\mathbb{Z}_n^{+}$ denotes the
cyclic group of order $n$.

**Question a**: Consider
the group 
$$
G=\mathbb{Z}_{n_1}^{+}\times
\mathbb{Z}_{n_2}^{+}\times
\ldots
\mathbb{Z}_{n_k}^{+}
$$
where $n_1,\ldots,n_k$ are pairwise relatively prime. 
Let $H$ be a finite group such that $|H|=|G|$. Is it true that in order to prove that $H\cong G$, it is suffices to prove that $H$ contains an element $a_i$ of order $n_i$ for each $i$ ? If not, how to prove that $H\cong G$ without describing a specific isomorphism?

**Question b** Consider
the group 
$$
G=\mathbb{Z}_{p^{k_1}}^{+}\times
\mathbb{Z}_{p^{k_2}}^{+}\times
\ldots
\mathbb{Z}_{p^{k_r}}^{+}
$$
where $p$ is a prime number and  $k_1\leq k_2\leq\ldots\leq k_r$. Let $H$ be a finite group such that $|H|=|G|$.
How to prove that $H\cong G$ without describing a specific isomorphism?

Thanks!

Comment: For question a, its sufficient. For question b, are the primes pairwise distinct?

Comment: I don't think it's sufficient, as he states it, considering that the $a_i$'s might not generate the group.

Comment: Thanks @Wuestenfux. In Question b, it is the same prime.

Comment: @PauloMourão But they do. In fact, with the notation of (a), we have that $$G\cong\Bbb Z^+_{n_1\cdot n_2\cdot\ldots\cdot n_k}$$

Comment: Thanks @Paulo Mourao. But the $a_i$'s are of order $n_i$, so they must generate the groups $\mathbb{Z}_{n_i}^{+}$

Comment: $H$ is an arbitrary group, just having elements of certain orders does not mean they generate $H$.

Comment: Sure, they do generate those groups, but that doesn't mean they generate $H$

Comment: The group $G\times\mathbb{Z}$ has one element of each order as you state and is not isomorphic to $G$.

Comment: @Paulo mourao: is the fact that $G$ is finite abelian not impotrtant?

Comment: Unless $H$ is a subgroup $G$, but you don't assume that either.

Comment: Why should that be important, if you're considering an arbitrary group $H$? Why can't it be $H=G\times\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: You right @Paulo Mouao. I will edit it again under the assumption that $H$ is finite.

Comment: That assumption is not enough. I could take $H=G\times \mathbb{Z}_{n_{k+1}}$ where $n_{k+1}$ is such that $n_1,\ldots,n_{k+1}$ are still relative primes. I just chose $\mathbb{Z}$ because it's faster to write.

Comment: I think you have to either assume that the elements that you found generate the group or assume that $H$ is a subgroup. Maybe assuming that they have the same cardinality would also be enough.

Comment: Thanks @Paulo Mouao ! Does that works also in Question b?

Comment: I'll try to write a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Question a:}$ I'm assuming you mean $\textit{pairwise}$ relatively prime, since them being just mutually relatively prime wouldn't do much for you, I don't think.

Assuming that, the answer is $\textbf{yes}$ and it comes from the fact that, if $H_i,H_j<H$ are the subgroups generated by $a_i$ and $a_j$, respectively, with $i\neq j$, then $H_i\cap H_j< H_i\implies |H_i\cap H_j|\mid n_i$ and $H_i\cap H_j<H_j\implies |H_i\cap H_j|\mid n_j$. Therefore $H_i\cap H_j=\{0\}$. This implies that the $a_i$'s generate $H$.

Then you can just consider the homomorphism $\varphi:G\to H$ determined by sending $\mathbb{Z}_{n_i}^+$ to $H_i$ in the obvious way $(1\mapsto a_i)$. Since the $a_i$'s generate $H$, it's surjective and therefore also injective, since the groups are finite with the same cardinality.

$\textbf{Question b:}$ Here the assumption that $|H|=|G|$ is not enough: If $G=\mathbb{Z}_2^+\times\mathbb{Z}_4^+$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}_8^+$, your conditions are verified: $2$ and $4$ have orders $4$ and $2$, respectively, in $H$. However, the groups are not isomorphic. You must further assume that such elements generate $H$, which in the previous question came free at the cost of their orders being pairwise relatively prime. The isomorphism is then given the same way.

Answer (score 0):

For question (a), it is not sufficient.  You need stronger conditions:

- either that $n_i$ are *pairwise* coprime, i.e., $\gcd(n_i,n_j)=1$ instead of just $\gcd(n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k)=1$.
- or the elements $a_i$ generate the group $H$.

To see why merely $n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k$ relatively prime fails, consider $n_1=2^3\times 3^2\times 5$, $n_2=3^3\times 5^2\times 7$, $n_3=5^3\times 7^2\times 2$, $n_4=7^3\times 2^2\times 3$.  Then $G$ is isomorphic to
$$
\prod_{p=2,3,5,7} (C_{p^3}\times C_{p^2}\times C_p)
$$
and the group
$$
H=C_{2^6\times 3^6\times 5^6\times 7^6}
$$
has the same number of elements as $G$, and since it has an element of order $2^6\times3^6\times5^6\times7^6$ it has an element of every factor of $2^6\times3^6\times5^6\times7^6$.  But $G$ is not cyclic, because every element has order divisible by $2^3\times3^3\times5^3\times7^3$.

Similarly for question (b), if you can exhibit $a_i$ of order $p^{k_i}$ in $H$ such that the $a_i$s generate $H$, then $G\cong H$.  But of course that is pretty much describing a specific isomorphism.